# how can I set Specific corner radious in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

how can I set specific corner radious? I have add label in cell.label is Multiline.

I tried Following code but problem is that height not increase.

```
+ (UIView *)roundCornersOnView:(UIView *)view onTopLeft:(BOOL)tl topRight:(BOOL)tr bottomLeft:(BOOL)bl bottomRight:(BOOL)br radius:(float)radius
{
    if (tl || tr || bl || br) {
        UIRectCorner corner = 0;
        if (tl) corner = corner | UIRectCornerTopLeft;
        if (tr) corner = corner | UIRectCornerTopRight;
        if (bl) corner = corner | UIRectCornerBottomLeft;
        if (br) corner = corner | UIRectCornerBottomRight;

        UIView *roundedView = view;
        UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:roundedView.bounds byRoundingCorners:corner cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)];
        CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        maskLayer.frame = roundedView.bounds;
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
        roundedView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
        return roundedView;
    }
    return view;
}


 // In cellforRow code like following
    [CommonUtils roundCornersOnView:cell.senderView onTopLeft:YES topRight:YES bottomLeft:YES bottomRight:NO radius:cell.senderView.frame.size.height / 2];
```

When I used Normal Code It's working & height Increase.

```
cell.label.layer.cornerRadius = cell.label.frame.size.height/2;
```

[image: imapliment]

please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you mean that height of Label is not increasing??

Comment: increased height but label not increased when i use upper code.means try to corner radius

Comment: Ok. So while setting normal corner radius `cell.label.layer.cornerRadius = cell.label.frame.size.height/2;` its working rite???

Comment: yes.......it working

Comment: Without adding a separate UIView,,, u just add like `UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:roundedView.bounds byRoundingCorners:corner cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)];
        CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        maskLayer.frame = roundedView.bounds;
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
        cell.label.layer.mask = maskLayer;`

Comment: check my code.. same as your code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149003/discussion-between-vignesh-davins-and-maulik).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use images for this, as all the chat app and messenger app did.
But you have to make some conditions for the images also for continue message from sender or receiver set the background image for cell accordingly.

You can check 
https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController

Comment: can you explain

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code is working, you can create a separate UIView area test

As for why your cell does not work, I think it is for other reasons